# Check if table exists in created Database in U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to check whether the table exists in database or not in U-SQL. Currently syntax is

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Logs;
CREATE TABLE Logs (
    date DateTime, 
    eventType int, 
    eventTime DateTime, 
    INDEX Index_EventType CLUSTERED (eventType ASC) 
    DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(eventType) INTO 3);
```

In this example, I just want to check if table exists or not in current database, I don't want to drop the table if it exists.

Basically I want to add if..else statements in U-SQL script for Table.Such as below:

```
IF NOT EXISTS Logs
{
 //Create table here   
}
else
{
 //Update table scripts
}
```

How to have this particular condition in U-SQL script?

Comment: by update table scripts are you trying to update the structure of the USQL table? As far as I know this is not supported. Can you elaborate on this or give part of the update script ?

Comment: @frictionlesspulley- I want to have if-else condition for table. If the table does not exist, my script will create table in database..but if table exists in database, I want to add alter statement in else clause.. Anyways got the answer...currently this functionality is not supported for table structures.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback for TABLE.EXISTS?

As a workaround, you could create a fake partitioned table that only contains a single partition, or use any of the workarounds maya specified in the comments to her answers.

Comment: have raised a feature request for this.

Comment: Thanks we are looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `IF NOT EXISTS` within the `CREATE` statement to achieve such behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Logs (
    date DateTime, 
    eventType int, 
    eventTime DateTime, 
INDEX Index_EventType CLUSTERED (eventType ASC) 
DISTRIBUTED BY HASH(eventType) INTO 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply maya, But I want to have an else statement also. If table doesnot exists, i will create it, else I will have scripts to alter table. Currently I have used "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Logs" syntax only.

Comment: Such option in fact exists for partitions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt796475.aspx), but not for tables.

Comment: An alternative would be to query usql.tables catalog view (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt826858.aspx), to check for table existence. You would however need to implement the IF/ELSE logic outside of U-SQL, as dynamic evaluation of IF is not supported...

Comment: @maya Do we have this supports now in u-sql. I checked the documentation but was not able to find any kind of function to support this

Comment: @shubham To my knowledge, no.